# mapper_parsing_exception in Elasticsearch 6.5.4

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect

I'm currently running an integration of:
Debezium MySQL connector source(v0.9.0F), 
Kafka connect(confluent platform v5.1.2) and 
ES(v6.5.4) on sink side.
Source connector is successfully able to parse tables in MySQL(checked in kafka logs), but below error occurs(with certain tables & specified columns) on sink side(ES).

```
"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",
\"reason\":\"Mapping definition for [column1] has unsupported parameters:  [null_value : 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z]\"
```

`column1`'s DDL is as follows:

```
`column1` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

However, there is no data present in table which is equal to `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` (not sure if that matters)

Similarly for another table's column:

```
"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",
\"reason\":\"Mapping definition for [column2] has unsupported parameters:  [null_value : ---]\"
```

`column2`'s DDL:

```
`column2` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '---'
```

The call stack of the error:

```
 at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.createMapping(JestElasticsearchClient.java:253)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.Mapping.createMapping(Mapping.java:65)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.write(ElasticsearchWriter.java:257)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.put(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:161)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:565)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:323)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:194)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-02-22 15:48:40,217] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=stage_refdata_company_essink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.W
orkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:587)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:323)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:194)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Cannot create mapping 
<mapping of table explanation>
 at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.createMapping(JestElasticsearchClient.java:253)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.Mapping.createMapping(Mapping.java:65)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.write(ElasticsearchWriter.java:257)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.put(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:161)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:565)
        ... 10 more
```

Data is present in table with the default value of `'---'`.

1. Why does ES throw an error at these 2 values?
2. `column2` has clearly specified `char(3)` as its type hence, `'---'` should be an accepted value.

Can you please help to resolve these errors?

How to avoid these errors in the future for some other custom default values?

Comment: See also https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues/285

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I would verify that the mapping of those indices in Elasticsearch is as expected - column1 type should be Date datatype, with the expected format, and column2 should be a keyword.
2. need to make sure that the sink is handling null/missing values as expected, and that the default values matches the elasticsearch template. There should be no issue indexing '---' into a keyword and '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z' into a date field, but maybe the sink is not converting to default values as expected.
3. You can also check ES log files, to get the full Mapper Parsing Exception logs, which would help in order to understand what was being indexed and why it failed, in details.

Comment: 1. I haven't provided any mapping in ES sink files, only the topic name and such.
2. Is there some documentation regarding these?
3. Let me check this out, thanks.

Comment: Hello! the ES log is simply showing a similar call stack to the one pasted. It points out the mapping error in the null value, but I'm not sure how or why it is one.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to index null values, and elasticsearch doesn't know how to. You have to specify the null values defaults in the index template and/or mapping: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html

Comment: I ran the command as specified in the link.

>curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/topicname" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "mappings": { "_doc": { "properties": { "column1": { "type": "date", "null_value": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" }}}}}'

but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Please ignore above, there was a typo in my command. It works perfectly with the link you have mentioned. Thanks!